# How to wrap output of echo in a span

Tags: php

Excuse the basic question but I'm new to PHP! How can I wrap the below text in span to change the font size of all the output fields. I managed the Name field but due to the periods I can't get the others working. Hopefully I can just wrap the entire echo in the same span.

```
echo "<span style=\"font-size: 10px;\">$row->Name</span>"."  ".$row->Country."  ".$row->Location."  ".$row->Category."  ".$row->Rating."  ".$row->Review."  ".$row->StartDate."  ".$row->EndDate."  ".$row->URL."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
echo '<span style="color:red;">'.$variable.'</span>';
```

Comment: By using this all values are wrap in a single span. If you want individual than wrap individually each value.

Comment: When I add the following I still see a php error....

echo '<span style="font-size: 10px;">'$row->Name."  ".$row->Country."  ".$row->Location."  ".$row->Category."  ".$row->Rating."  ".$row->Review."  ".$row->StartDate."  ".$row->EndDate."  ".$row->URL.'</span>';

Comment: because . is missing after closing of <span> echo '<span style="font-size: 10px;">' -> here

Comment: I'm fine with all values in a single span as I'm applying the same span settings to everything

Comment: Try this:

echo '<span style="font-size: 10px;">'.$row->Name." ".$row->Country." ".$row->Location." ".$row->Category." ".$row->Rating." ".$row->Review." ".$row->StartDate." ".$row->EndDate." ".$row->URL.'</span>';

Comment: Grt, if this works for you than just accept the answer :P